# Is it possible to save different values on address 0 and 1 in EEPROM?

Tags: arduino-uno, eeprom

I want to save different values on address 0 and 1 on eeprom I tried to change it but when I put data on address 0 and also put data on address 1 the address 0 change its value stored into random number and vice versa .. Is it possible to change the value of respective address without affecting others ..

**CODE**

```
in the setup
     int eepromSize=EEPROM.length();
      Serial.print("EEPROM found, size=");
      Serial.println(eepromSize);
        // Get the last fade value (as an integer)
      EEPROM.get(0, WATEREQFORN1);
      Serial.print("Last Value N1: ");
      Serial.println(WATEREQFORN1);

      EEPROM.get(1, WATEREQFORN2);
      Serial.print("Last Value N2: ");
      Serial.println(WATEREQFORN2);
```

The user will input the value that will be save in eeprom i use switch because the user will input like this example .. 100A or 23B

```
case 'A':
        Serial.print("Case A got ");
        Serial.println(val);
        WATEREQFORN1 = val;

            EEPROM.put(0, WATEREQFORN1);
            Serial.print("DATA SAVE TO EEPROM");

        break;
      case 'B':
        Serial.print("Case B got ");
        Serial.println(val);
         WATEREQFORN2 = val;
         EEPROM.put(1, WATEREQFORN2);
         Serial.print("DATA SAVE TO EEPROM");

        break;
```

The problem is, when I change/write value into address 0 and after that change/write also into address 1 the value on address 0 also change into different random numbers.

Comment: Yes. Post your code so we can see where you went wrong.

Comment: @Majenko I edit my question and add my code ,

Comment: What are `WATEREQFORN1` and `WATEREQFORN2`? You only show a bit of your code, and have omitted what may be the most important parts - your variable definitions.

Comment: `unsigned int WATEREQFORN1;
unsigned int WATEREQFORN2;` That is the value the user enter sir .. example `200A` it will be get by `case a` and be assign in `WATEREQFORN1`as show in my code `WATEREQFORN1 = val` the `val` initially hold the serial value `200` and pass to `WATERECFORN1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable names in all upper case is a style problem you should address.  Conventionally, C and C++ programmers use all-upper-case names to designate defined constants or macros.  Contravening that convention can lead to confusion if other people use or maintain the code.  Instead of `WATEREQFORN1` consider `waterEq1`, etc.

The problem of your second value overwriting part of the first in EEPROM is an allocation problem.  Presumably the `WATEREQ...` variables are multiple bytes in length.  `EEPROM.get()` and `put()` read and write data types with multiple bytes using several consecutive bytes of EEPROM.  For example, if `WATEREQFORN1` is a real and takes 4 bytes, it will occupy cells 0, 1, 2, 3 in EEPROM.

The following code snippet shows a way to automatically and systematically allocate EEPROM space.  The `sizeof` operator returns the size in bytes of its argument.  Thus, an expression like `WaterAddr2=WaterAddr1+sizeof waterEq1` correctly sets `WaterAddr2` to be the next available cell after `waterEq1`, no matter what type `waterEq1` is.

```
enum { WaterAddr1=0, WaterAddr2=WaterAddr1+sizeof waterEq1, DelayAddr=WaterAddr2+sizeof waterEq2 };
...
case 'A': 
  waterEq1 = val;
  EEPROM.put(WaterAddr1, waterEq1);
  break;
case 'B': 
  waterEq2 = val;
  EEPROM.put(WaterAddr2, waterEq2); 
  break;
case 'D':
  Delay = val;
  EEPROM.put(DelayAddr, Delay);
  break;
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks I think thats  the problem , I follow your advice and It Works like a charm .. :D

Comment: the allocation is the problem ..

Answer (score 1):

EEPROM.put() and EEPROM.get() write or read the object you pass them. An `int` is 2 bytes so that is what they write or read. It sounds like you intended for the functions to only handle 1 byte. In that case, make the your variable's data type something that is 1 byte, such as `int8_t`; otherwise allocate 2 bytes of EEPROM to each.

Update: 
It works because you had only allocated 1 byte in EEPROM for each variable but you store 2-byte variables. Now you're storing 1-byte variables, which matches your EEPROM allocation.

Comment: So instead of `unsigned int` i will use `byte` ? because i only want to save numbers.

Comment: It works now that i change the `unsigned int WATEREQFORN1;` into `byte WATEREQFORN1` i dont know why but it works , when i write new data to  `WATEREQFORN2` the `WATEREQFORN1` dont change into random numbers

Answer (score 0):

Probably WATEREQFORN1 is an int or word, at least more than one byte.

If you write a 2 byte value on address 0, it will occupy address 0 and 1.

When you overwrite address 1 (again with a 2 byte value), it will occupy addres 2 and 3, destroying the LSB part of the value written to byte 0.

Try writing on address 0 and 2 (or 0 and 4 when using 4 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to change the value of respective address without affecting others ..

Yes, if the two values are 8-bit types.

Otherwise, No.